# Is it normal for webhosts to increase hosting price drastically after the first year?

Tags: web-hosting

I signed up with a web host a year ago and remember paying only around $15 for the year at the time. Probably less. Now my renewal is coming up and they want to charge me nearly $40 per year.

They have great support, but I feel this is a bit expensive for hosting a low-traffic website. Is this common practice? I would hate to take all the time and energy to migrate my website to a different host only to have them do the same thing after a year.

Comment: Generally - Yes. There is often an introductory price and the annual price for renewal. My concern is how much per month your renewal is. Like they say around here, **Holy Heck!!** Is this Network Solutions? ;-) Check out other hosts for better prices, but do not go for cheap. Go for quality.

Comment: Oh sorry it's per year. Edited the OP.

Comment: Oh. Hells bells! That's gang good!! Don't change if you are happy. You cannot complain about that price!

Comment: In my experience... no, this is not normal. However, if this was initially an "introductory price" for new customers then that should have been clearly stated at the time. (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is common for shared hosting plans. For VPS and dedicated servers, it is not so common as billing usually happens every month (they generally offer 1 or 2 months of free hosting/credits in case of VPS).

In shared hosting space, sellers do not call it 'introductory offer' or anything but they just mention that renewal will happen at $40 (or some other number) per year.

If you're happy with the hosting/support, do not change the host as $40 per year is very reasonable specially when support is great.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a lot of experience with webhosts and it seemed like a big jump from what I was first paying. Tbh, they have great support but I was just so surprised at the price increase. Good to know it's reasonable so I will stay with them. :)